# Add the router-store configuration RouterState.Full throws a cryptic error message

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-router-store

I just started to implement the `router-store` of the ngrx library. I followed their instructions to implement the complete router there.

In the end the `RouterState.Full` configuration throws the error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot add property **NG_ELEMENT_ID**, object is not extensible

On the other hand when I use the `RouterState.Minimal` configuration it works like expected.

Link of the ngrx configurations: https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/configuration

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Two ways to solve this:

- use minimal (for most of the cases I've seen, you don't need Full)
- disable [runtime checks](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks)

Comment: disabling runtime checks should not be the correct answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the answer for now. https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2016